# How to make a stack background (Color gradient and photo) in css

Tags: css, background-image

I Made a flutter app and I would like to convert it to a website, so far so good but I want the same background of the app to be on the website.

here is a screenshot of the app background

[background image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGnIc.png)

In this photo I used stack with two big circles on each sides with distinctive colors and a blur image in the middle.

Any suggestion would help,
I have tried a lot, and many works but can't get the results I want (same as the app)

Comment: Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[css background-image](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image) can get the result, see the examples 4.

```css
background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5), rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.5)),
                  url("../../media/examples/lizard.png");
```